# C function in Excel 64 bit does not work as a worksheet function but works well in VBA

Tags: c++, c, excel, vba, worksheet-function

I am writing a 64 bit Dll in C which is then used in Excel 64 bit, and I am following a sample project from https://sites.google.com/site/jrlhost/links/excelcdll.

The example is simple. We write a function in C which is to return the square value of an input. The function is exported in DLL and then used in Excel 64 bit.

I am facing the exact same problem as in the example:

> "However, when you use squareForEXL as a worksheet function, it results in errors. On my desktop, it returns the correct result (e.g., "= squareForEXL(10)" yields 100) but then gives an "Out of Stack Space" error, either at some point when calling the function or when Excel is closed. On my laptop, it returns an incorrect result (e.g., "= squareForEXL(10)" yields 0). On both, Excel sometimes crashes."

The C function (squareForEXL) works fine when used in VBA, but it does not work as a worksheet function. One workaround is proposed in the article but I still want to see if there is any way to resolve the issue directly.

Below is the C and VBA code:

```
double _stdcall squareForEXL (double *x)
{
    return *x * *x;
}

Declare PtrSafe Function squareForEXL Lib "C:\Working\XLSquare\x64\Debug\XLSquare.dll" (ByRef x As Double) As Double
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the squareForExl given in the example. That is you need,

```
double _stdcall squareForEXL (double &x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```